# Bluetooth mouse auto-connect after wake up?

Tags: 16.04, mouse

if i wake up my thinkpad, mouse don't connect automatic. I must turn off bluetooth, turn on, click to turn on "connect mouse".

Is some fix for it?
I have 16.04.

thanks